# dispatch_queue name and thread

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

there's a button method :

```
-(void) buttonTapped:(id) sender{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("countQueue", NULL), ^{
        sleep(10);
        NSLog(@"%d",self.count++);
    });
}
```

self.count is property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int count;
```

I want to know if I create the "countQueue" many times by click the button ,

1. how many threads is running for processing task of countQueue?
2. because the block need to run in 10 seconds, if I click the button every 2 seconds, then it will create a new queue, how the system process the previous task? just cancel it?

Comment: Why do you want to use GCD for this? And why keep creating new queues?

Comment: the situation like if I click a button ,the app should download an image from server, it will take 10 seconds

Comment: If you're downloading images [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) make your life much easier, doing this gracefully, asynchronously, caching, etc. Using their respective `UIImageView` categories and removing your own code for asynchronous image retrieval might make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Each call to `dispatch_queue_create()` creates a *new queue*, even if a queue with the same label already exists. The label is only meant as a tool to identify the queue during debugging. Arbitrary many queues with the same label can exist at the same time.
- Since you don't keep a strong reference to the queue, it is destroyed automatically after all blocks dispatched to the queue have finished.
- How the system allocates threads to queues is an implementation detail of GCD.
- In your case, it might be easier to use `dispatch_after()`.

*Edit:* After reading your comment, I assume that there is a better solution to your problem,
such as updating the property if the image download has actually finished. How to do this depends on the method used for the download. One example would be the completion handler
of `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` of `NSURLConnection`.